# Ordner nicht angegeben with OmniPascal in VSCode

Tags: omnipascal

People get the error when opening a file in Visual Studio Code when using [OmniPascal](https://bitbucket.org/Wosi/omnipascalissues/issues/24/message-ordner-nicht-angegeben-when):

[image]

> Ordner nicht angegeben

which translates to:

> Folder not specified

The first thought to ensure the paths in user *settings.json* are set:

- `objectpascal.delphiInstallationPath`
- `objectpascal.objectpascal.searchPath`

Would of course be a wrong tree to bark up:

**settings.json**:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "objectpascal.delphiInstallationPath": "D:\\Programs\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\14.0",
    "objectpascal.searchPath": "D:\\Delphi Components"
}
```

The error is definitely coming from OmniPascal, as it is a string inside

> bin\win\OmniPascalServer.exe

[image]

### I'm not the only person to get this

[Anonymous](https://bitbucket.org/Wosi/omnipascalissues/issues/24/message-ordner-nicht-angegeben-when) has the same issue:

> When I open a .pas file by right clicking on the file in windows explorer, the file opens correctly, but then a messagedialog appears with "Ordner nicht angegeben"' and an OK button.

### Is there a way to debug Code?

I can see inside VSCode there is a variable to the *workspace root path*:

**objectPascalServiceClient.js**

```
var config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('objectpascal');  
var delphiSDK = config.get('delphiInstallationPath', '');
var searchPath = config.get('searchPath', '');                                                                
var workspacePath = vscode.workspace.rootPath;
if (typeof delphiSDK == 'undefined')
   delphiSDK = "";
if (typeof searchPath == 'undefined')
   searchPath = "";                            

if (isWin) {
    childProcess = cp.spawn(path.join(__dirname, 'bin/win/OmniPascalServer.exe'), [workspacePath, delphiSDK, searchPath]);
                    }
```

### Is there source code?

It looks like OmniPascal is abandonware. Is there source code out there where someone can try to decipher exactly?

The *real* question is how to get rid of the modal dialog that blocks using the window.

Comment: I'm aware there wasn't much publicly visible activity about OmniPascal in the last time but I can promise a new version is about to be released soon. The bug will be fixed in that version. I expect the new version to come within the next week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It looks like OmniPascal is abandonware

No it's definetely not abandonware even though there was no new public release within the last months. OmniPascal is still in active development.

> The real question is how to get rid of the modal dialog that blocks using the window.

This error message is coming from `OmniPascalServer.exe` shipped with the OmniPascal plugin for VSCode in (the current) version 0.10.0 released on 2016-04-14.

**Workaround for version < 0.11.0**

As far as I know this error message only appears when a **file is opened in Visual Studio Code instead of a folder**. So the simplest workaround is to open the folder which contains the file(s) you want to work with:

- *By command line*: Type `code C:\Projects\MyProjectRootFolder`
- *With the Windows Explorer*: Perform a right click on the folder (or a white area inside the folder) and select *Open with Code*. **Do not select a .pas file to open VSCode!**
- *From within VSCode*: Go to `File -> Open Folder...`

**Or apply the hotfix**

- Open the file `C:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions\Wosi.omnipascal-0.10.0\objectPascalServiceClient.js`
- Replace this line

  ```
  var workspacePath = vscode.workspace.rootPath;
  ```

  with these lines

  ```
  var workspacePath = vscode.workspace.rootPath;
  if (typeof workspacePath == 'undefined') {
      var filePath = vscode.workspace.textDocuments[0].fileName;
      workspacePath = path.dirname(filePath);
  }
  ```

Now the error should no longer appear.

Comment: Please let me know if the described workaround doesn't work.

Comment: That does it; thanks! I was using VSCode as my editor to view a file out of source control (it copies the file to a temp location and then launches Code.exe). There does seem to be a separate issue, that OmniPascal doesn't handle a file being viewed (the second Code.exe window opens, but nothing ever appears). I assume its related to the language server not being able to handle being communicated to from separate processes. But, as you said, OP doesn't support being used as a .pas viewer.

Comment: Great that it works! *"the second Code.exe window opens, but nothing ever appears"* -> When a second Code.exe is opened then there should spawn a second OmniPascalServer.exe process as soon as a PAS file is opened. When Code.exe doesn't show a file then there is something wrong with VSCode or the way you start it. *"the language server not being able to handle being communicated to from separate processes"* ->  Each Code instance has its own OP instance *"OP doesn't support being used as a .pas viewer"* -> Yes it is. At least it should be. Please tell me when you still have issues.