# How to make OmniPascal work with FPC?

Tags: omnipascal

I've installed both FreePascal compiler and OmniPascal extension for VisualStudio code, but code completion doesn't work. In the manual you are saying that I need to write the path to Delphi compiler int the user settings, but nothing is said about FPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the `omnipascal.freePascalSourcePath` setting to the folder that contains the FreePascal sources
- Set the `omnipascal.defaultDevelopmentEnvironment` setting to `FreePascal`
- Restart Visual Studio Code.

**Example**:

```
"omnipascal.freePascalSourcePath": "C:\\lazarus\\fpc"
"omnipascal.defaultDevelopmentEnvironment": "FreePascal"
```

This will instruct the OmniPascal language server to lookup Pascal units (`.pas` and `.pp` files) in that directory and all its subtrees recursively.

Comment: Take a look here for a temporary workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862043/ordner-nicht-angegeben-with-omnipascal-in-vscode

Comment: @Wosi what's the state of Linux support now? I've installed your extension under Linux and pointed the configuration to my Freepascal source files. When I now type in some standard pascal commands it seems that code completion works... Or am I wrong? 

Do you have a more-in-detail overview how to work with your plugin? It would be nice to add the Lazarus sources, too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Marc It's still running on Windows only. When (almost) all of Delphi's language features are supported it will be extended to other platforms and editors.

Comment: Since some people were confused by the comments: OmniPascal is now working on Mac and Linux as well.