# How can I work with FPC from OmniPascal?

Tags: omnipascal

I tried this commands in `VSCode` on Windows

```
"omnipascal.delphiInstallationPath": "C:\\lazarus\\fpc"
"omnipascal.delphiInstallationPath": "C:\\lazarus\\fpc\\3.0.2\\source"
"omnipascal.freePascalSourcePath": "C:\\lazarus\\fpc"
"omnipascal.freePascalSourcePath": "C:\\lazarus\\fpc\\3.0.2\\source"
```

Also I tried same commands on Linux with `usr/share/fpcsrc`. But I can not work FPC from VSCode - OmniPascal.

How can I run it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make OmniPascal work with FPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957074/how-to-make-omnipascal-work-with-fpc)

Comment: What does *I can not work FPC* mean? Do you have FPC installed in `C:\Lazarus\FPC`? What specific problem do you have that means *I can not work FPC*?

Comment: @KenWhite thanks. I already looked that link. I want code completion like [this](http://www.omnipascal.com/img/portfolio/codecompletion1.gif). But it's not work for me like [this](https://s26.postimg.org/anxde1pc9/image.gif). I wanna see `FPC` standard libraries. Also I installed FPC to `C:\lazarus\fpc` and `usr/share/fpcsrc`.

Comment: @İbrahim I updated the answer of the other question maybe you should take a look at it againg. Does it work better when you restart VSCode after changing the settings?